# Class name not defined

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and I have a problem.

I created a class, and when I instanciate it, Python says it has not been defined.

Here is my code.

My class `dirNode`, in the file `dirTree.py`:

```
class dirNode:
    'Represente a directory of a files system'

    # Create an instance of the class
    def __init__(self, path, name, parent=None):
        self.path=path
        self.name=name
        self.nbDir=0
        self.nbFile=0
        if parent is not None:
            self.parent=parent
        else:
            self.parent=None


    # Add a sub-directory
    def addDir(self, name, dirNode):
        self.dirs[name]=dirNode
        self.nbDir+=1

    # Print the number of sub-directory
    def printDirCount(self):
        print self.nbDir


    # Add a file
    def addFile(self, name, fileNode):
        self.files[name]=fileNode
        self.nbFile+=1

    # Print the number of files
    def printFilesCount(self):
        print self.nbFile
```

Here is my "main" code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import dirTree


direct=sys.argv[1]
isRoot=1

print direct

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(direct):
    if (isRoot==1):
        rootDir=dirNode(root, root)
        curDir=rootDir
        isRoot=0
    else:
        parent=curDir
        curDir=dirNode(root, root, parent)

    for name in dirs:
        print "foo"
```

Here is what Python says:

```
$./test.py datas/
datas/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 78, in <module>
    rootDir=dirNode(root, root)
NameError: name 'dirNode' is not defined
```

Comment: `from dirTree import dirNode`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing the module `dirTree`, but not the class `dirNode` itself.

Try changing your import to `from dirTree import dirNode`. Alternatively, you could instantiate the class by doing `dirtree.dirNode(...)`, but I wouldn't recommend it for your case (see comments below for further explanation).

Lastly, please make sure your code inside the class' `__init__` method is properly indented (not sure if it just broke when you pasted it here of it it's actually like that in your code) :)

Comment: Yes, it's the copy/past. Changed

Comment: Where did you find that something like `dirtree.dirNode(...)` is not recommended?

Comment: @Matthias I should have been clearer in my statement, I'll edit it to reflect that. I meant to say **I don't recommend it**. To me, it only makes sense instantiating a class via `<module_name>.<class_name>()` if you have several modules imported in that file and you want to avoid name clashes. Otherwise, it just pollutes the code and is more needless work to type (could also cause you to forget that you should write the module along with the class and generate silly errors that might consume a few pricey minutes of your time :)).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your class and main are not present in same file. If that's the case then you need to import your class into your main file `from dirTree import dirNode`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
rootDir = dirTree.dirNode(root, root)
```

or keep the line as is and change your import statement to:

```
from dirTree import dirNode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dirTree import dirNode
```

What to do is 
from _________ import ________ <---- what variable are you calling that?